# Google Sheets - Identify if one of many matches any in an array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I am trying to determine if an array of values in Google Sheets has any matches within another array of values. The data set is constantly expanding, so I want to use an Arrayformula to handle it.

---

This is the closest I've gotten so far:

`=ARRAYFORMULA( IF( IFERROR( VLOOKUP( SPLIT($K2:K, ",", TRUE, TRUE ), FILTER( Tags!$A$2:$A, Tags!$A$2:$A<>"", Tags!$C$2:$C=1 ), 1, FALSE ), FALSE )<>FALSE, TRUE ))`

The data is comma separated in a single cell, so I start by using the `split` function to separate each value. I then `vlookup` the value in a  filtered table of values that are being categorized by type.

`=VLOOKUP( SPLIT( $K2:K, ",", TRUE, TRUE ), FILTER( Tags!$A$2:$A, Tags!$A$2:$A<>"", Tags!$C$2:$C=1 )`

I then use `IFERROR` to mark any items not found as FALSE, and an `IF` function to mark the rest as TRUE.

`=IF( IFERROR( VLOOKUP(above), FALSE )<>FALSE, TRUE ))`

By wrapping it all in an `arrayformula`, I've been able to produce an array of T/F values based on the IDs in the cell.

---

**I want the result to be a single column that tells me if *any are true***.

I would try to use `join` or `sum` of these as numbers, but those don't work with an arrayformula and the data will constantly be expanding so it would require constantly adjusting the cells to more columns.

I feel like using Query may allow me more flexibility here, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around using it very well so I haven't gotten far on that.

Here's a spreadsheet containing the data I'm working with (irrelevant data is hidden/removed): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DcTq2hsX7tNfw2f31oPzVqZu8V7JVKNAJUdqQMcinFI/edit#gid=1916289043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly the following formula should produce your desired results:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(arrayformula(if(iferror(
    VLOOKUP(SPLIT($K3:K, ",", TRUE, TRUE), 
       QUERY(Tags!A2:C28,"SELECT A,'z' WHERE C=1 label 'z' ''"), 1, 0),
           FALSE)<>FALSE, "YES","xxxxx")),LEN(A3:A)>1)),,999^99))))
```

*(I changed the resulting data to `xxxxx` and `YES` just so as to make it easier to read. You can change them to whatever you want)*

[image]

Comment: This works great, though I don't fully understand how it works. For any future reference, I threw that entire thing within another array search formula to narrow it down to a single T/F value by searching for TRUE within the result (I changed the results YES/xxxxx to TRUE/FALSE). This seems to take care of things, thanks!


`=arrayformula(iferror(if(search(TRUE, `

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :)